# How can we use properly the innerHTML value in javascript when it has image?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In my jsp page, I want to list all the file names and subfolder names in a directory with corresponding images. When it is file , show file image; when it is a subfolder ,show a folder image. After listing file names and subfolder names , when a click a file, the jsp page show the content of the file; when double click the subfolder name , the jsp page will show the file names and subfolder names in the current directory. the screen-shot is as follows:
[image: list of file names and subfolder names]

The part of code to show the file names and subfolder names are as follows:

```
<% File directory = new File(var_path);
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            File[] list = directory.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if(list[i].isDirectory()) {
                    out.print("<TR> <TD ondblclick=list_files("+i+") id="+i+"><img src="+ "/brt-example/images/folder.png />"+list[i].getName()+"</TD></TR>");  
                }else{
                    out.print("<TR><TD onclick=show_file_content("+i+") id="+i+"><img src="+ "/brt-example/images/book.png />"+list[i].getName()+"</TD></TR>"); 
                }
            }
        }
    %>
```

Then, I call the corresponding javascript functions according to onclick or double click event. take onclick event as exampe, the part of the code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_file_content(id)
        {

                    var id = id;
                    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function()
                    {
                      var file_name = document.getElementById (id).innerHTML;
                      alert(file_name);
                    }
         }
</script>
```

But the alert message box shows me "< img src="/brt-example/images/book.png">postgreSQL.rptdesign" . Actually , I want to get only "postgreSQL.rptdesign". How can I read only file names without image tag when I click the file name ? Could you give me some suggestions ? thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: If you want to stick to the DOM / pure JavaScript approach, then you should switch to [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with "textContent" attribute. I replaced the code :

```
var file_name = document.getElementById (id).innerHTML;
```

with :

```
var file_name = document.getElementById (id).textContent;
```

And it works properly.

Thanks all of you !

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are looking for [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Replace `var file_name = document.getElementById (id).innerHTML;`

To `var file_name = document.getElementById (id).innerText;`

Example

```html
<div>
    <img src="url_to_img" /> And text too
</div>
<hr />
<button onclick="alert(document.querySelector('div').innerHTML);">alert div.innerHTML</button>
<button onclick="alert(document.querySelector('div').innerText);">alert div.innerText</button>
```

**jQuery version**

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img src="url_to_img" /> And text too
</div>
<hr />
<button onclick="alert($('div').html());">alert $(div).html()</button>
<button onclick="alert($('div').text());">alert $(div).text()</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your instructions.But, it should be :  var file_name = document.getElementById (id).textContent; Instead of innerText.

Comment: `it should be`? Says who ;)?